# Лимиты использования многопользовательского SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Каковы предельные количественные характеристики SQLite при многопользовательском использовании (с использование WAL) на сетевом диске? Размер, количество соединений?

Предполагается одновременная работа 150-200 пользователей, 20-25 таблиц от 10 от 20 000 записей в каждой. Целесообразно ли использовать SQLite в качестве альтернативы Access, или забить на файл-серверные базы и взять обычную серверную?

Comment: А это не смущает: [All processes using a database must be on the same host computer; WAL does not work over a network filesystem.](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)?

Comment: Судя по всему, я как-то не внимательно прочел. Спасибо.